# how solr search works with starts with+

Tags: search, solr

How solr search works with starts with '+' symbol,  search phone number with  '+32498516 where phone number saved in database like:  +32498516141,+32498516345

My Concern here :
Start with:

+32498516

```
q=cellPhone%3A%28%28%2B32498516*%29%29&start=0&rows=1048577&fl=firstName,lastName,indexType,userExtKey,resumeId,externalId,shareProfile,candidateId,publicIntranetNR,userId,id,score&fq=indexType%3ACANDIDATE+AND+%28shareProfile%3Atrue+OR+country%3AUS%29

32498516
q=cellPhone%3A%28%2832498516*%29%29&start=0&rows=1048577&fl=firstName,lastName,indexType,userExtKey,resumeId,externalId,shareProfile,candidateId,publicIntranetNR,userId,id,score&fq=indexType%3ACANDIDATE+AND+%28shareProfile%3Atrue+OR+country%3AUS%29
```

In Both cases getting same number of candidate in result :

Comment: I would suggest you not to index the + sign while indexing ...and while performing the search query you can skip the + sign...You can ignore the + sign...You need to build a custom fieldType for your field where in you can ignore the + sign

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your current fieldType for your field cellPhone...

Comment: current field type of cellphone is VARCHAR2(100 BYTE).

Comment: Not the database type...in your solr schema.xml.. the cellPhone field must be defined...what is the fieldType of it

Comment: <field name="cellPhone" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: if you notice your + sign gets encoded in the ur as %2B...

Comment: You can find a nice list of corresponding URL encoded characters on W3Schools at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp.

Comment: `+` has special meaning in the default Lucene syntax (it means a term is required to match to be included). You can escape the character by prefixing it with a backslash. `cellPhone:\+3249...`

Comment: I tried all both not working , below are my codes , where Case'EXACT' are working fine but rest are not giving the correct result :             case STARTSWITH:
        if(isHanaTextSearch){
          convertedString =  actualString +"*";
        } else {
          convertedString = ParamNames.OPEN_PARENTHISIS + actualString + "*" + ParamNames.CLOSE_PARENTHISIS;
        }
        break;

Comment: Below are my EXACT case , which working fine when we search with exactly + sign +32498516141.  case EXACT:
        if(isHanaTextSearch){
          convertedString =  "\"" + actualString + "\"" ;
        }else{
          convertedString = ParamNames.OPEN_PARENTHISIS + "\"" + actualString + "\"" + ParamNames.CLOSE_PARENTHISIS;
        }

Comment: Please help me someone :case EXACT:
        convertedString = ParamNames.OPEN_PARENTHISIS + "\"" + actualString + "\"" + ParamNames.CLOSE_PARENTHISIS;
 case CONTAINS:
  convertedString = ParamNames.OPEN_PARENTHISIS + actualString + ParamNames.CLOSE_PARENTHISIS;
case STARTSWITH:
  convertedString = ParamNames.OPEN_PARENTHISIS + " " + actualString + "*" + ParamNames.CLOSE_PARENTHISIS;

Issue with  STARTSWITH when i am searching with cellPhone: +32498516

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for the help, its workout.