# how solr search works with contains +phone

Tags: search, solr, contains

actualString : 32498516141, +32498516141

```
convertedString = ParamNames.OPEN_PARENTHISIS + actualString + ParamNames.CLOSE_PARENTHISIS;
```

contains search not working in solr when we are searching with +32498516,+3249, 32498516,324 etc

Comment: is this the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963900/how-solr-search-works-with-starts-with?

Comment: this search with 'contains' , that was 'start-with'

Comment: Let us all know what is your schema.xml and fields types used for the field...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by parts of a word, you need apply, for example, N-Gram Tokenizer, `<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10"/>`

eg.

In: `"bicycle"`

Out: `"bicy", "bicyc", "icyc", "icycl", "cycl", "cycle", "ycle"`

In this case you will be able to search by the part of word. You need apply the NGramTokenizerFactory for both analyzers:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

You can also try the below query analyzer. It all depends on your requirement.

```
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

You can modify or add the field types in your `schema.xml` and apply it to your field.
Once done restart the server, re-index the data. You can verify the above fieldType for your field if the data matches using solr admin tool.

I have used the below field type and done the analysis using the solr tool.

Here is the field type :

```
    <fieldType name="custome_field_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
        <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Please find the images where it shows how the tokens are created while indexing and querying the data. It also highlights the matches.

[image: Analysis image one with +32 query value]

[image: Analysis image one with 9851 query value]

Comment: But what about the phone number having like : Input: 32498516141, +32498516141, Output: 32,324,249,8516,16141,+32,+324,249,8516,16141,+32498516,+324985,+3249851

Comment: @SatishPrasad:Did the answer helped you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit Bashetti. I got your answers but some how in my local system solr is  not working with special character